# multi chart in python

Tags: python, charts

I have the following code:

```
pl.bar (x1,x2)
pl.show()
pl.plot(x1,x3)
pl.show
```

It generated two separate chart one bar chart and one plot. I want to have bar and plot in one single graph. Could you please let me know how I can make it?

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: What is `pl`? It seems that you have problem in your code, check: `pl.show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `pl` is `matplotlib.pylab`:

```
pl.bar(x1,x2)
pl.plot(x1,x3,color='r')
pl.show()
```

Note the change of color for contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the first call to pl.show().   This way you add both items to pl before showing it.